# ¿El orden de los atributos del JSON al enviar una petición importa?

Tags: json, rest, https

Me he topado con la situación en la que debo enviar peticiones JSON a un servicio de tercero y pasa que los distintos Schemas, su estructura es idéntica a excepción que el orden cambia. Por ejemplo:

En la primera estructura:

```
{
 "persona": {
    "numero_identificacion": "12345687-9",
    "nombre_completo": "Jason Doe"
  },
 "otro_atributo": {
    "atributo":"valor",
    ...
 },
 ...
}
```

En la segunda estructura:

```
{
 "persona": {
    "nombre_completo": "Jason Doe",
    "numero_identificacion": "12345687-9"
  },
 "otro_atributo": {
    "atributo":"valor",
    ...
 },
 ...
}
```

¿Se podrá enviar de una sola forma para ambas estructura mediante peticion HTTP?

Me puedan confirmar si puedo enviarlo como uno solo para ambos por medio de petición HTTP sin importar el orden. De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En principio, el orden de las propiedades no importaría, salvo casos muy particulares en los  que, por la razón que fuera, el consumidor de dicho JSON lo leyera como cadena en vez de como objeto.

Cosa distinta sería en el caso de que enviásemos un array, pues en dicho caso el orden sí podría ser importante.

En el caso que presentas no me parece que sea un problema.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho esa aclaración

Answer (score 0):

No debería importar, pero deberías hacer test primero. Puedes encontrar mas info aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870416/does-the-sequence-of-the-values-matter-in-a-json-object

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo revise y me terminó de confirmar la pregunta que tenía